# Update a property in an object

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a generic way to update the properties of an object, in a typesafe manner.

My naive solution has (at least) two things wrong with it.

```
interface ISettings {
  isOpen: boolean;
  width: number;
  language: 'EN' | 'NL';
}

const settings: ISettings = {
  isOpen: true,
  width: 300,
  language: 'EN'
};

function updateSettings(key: keyof ISettings, value: any) {
  settings[key] = value;
}

updateSettings('isOpen', false);
```

To my surprise `settings[key]` evaluates to the type "never", even though the `key` was specified to be a `keyof ISettings`.

The second issue is that I am looking for a way to do typecheking on `value`. It's now typed as `any`, but the type should be same as the value type in the interface: in this case `boolean`. Something dynamic like `ISettings[key]` won't work, but I feel like I need something similar.

Comment: You need your function to be *generic* for this to work, and you need to use an *indexed access type* for `value`.  Both are shown in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862727/8926512) in particular explains how you should type the signature of `updateSettings`.